# google chrome not following window open parameters

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I use the following to open a new window in a browser.

For some reason Google Chrome (11.0.696.65) doesn't use the parameters, specifically the menubar and toolbar ones which are important. Without them the user can't print preview the page, for example. It works fine in IE, Firefox and Safari. Any ideas?

```
function myopen(filename,windowname) {
    var mywindow;
    mywindow = window.open(filename,windowname,'width=1000,height=640,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes');
    mywindow.focus();
}
```